# Passing data from a class which is Lifecycle observer to the Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have a class **BatteryInfo** which is a **life-cycle observer** and in this class, there is a **BroadCastReceiver** which is responsible for getting all battery information. This class is working perfectly with the **lifecycle of Activity** from where I have called it. This means it is **registering the broadcast on activity created** and **unRegister on closing activity**. But I am confused about how to access this broadcast live information in Activity.

```
class BatteryInfo(
        private val _context: Context,
        private val _lifecycle: Lifecycle,
    ): LifecycleObserver {

        private var _enabled = false

        init {
            _lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        }

        private val broadcastBatteryInfoListener = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

                intent?.let {

                    val level = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
                    val temperature = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1)
                    val voltage = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1)
                    val technology = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY, -1)
                    val plugged = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)
                    val health = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, -1)



                  //  Log.d("TAG", String.format("%.1f", voltage / 1000f) + " V")
                }
            }
        }


        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
        fun start() {
          //  if (_enabled) {
                _context.registerReceiver(broadcastBatteryInfoListener,
                    IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
                )
          // }
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
        fun stop() {
            _context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastBatteryInfoListener)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        fun destroy() {
            _lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        }


        // connect if not connected
        fun enable() {
            _enabled = true

            if (_lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
                start()
            }
        }
    }
```

**I am Calling this class from MainActivity onCreate method like this**

```
BatteryInfo(this, lifecycle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with the help of **MutableLiveData & LiveData** but I am not sure it is a **perfect solution** or a **hacky solution**. I want to do a perfect solution that follows **MVVM**, **clean-architecture**, and **SOLID principle** without the creation of multiple objects because it is very costly.

```
 class BatteryInfo(
            private val _context: Context,
            private val _lifecycle: Lifecycle
        ) : LifecycleObserver {

            val map = HashMap<String, Int>()
            private var _enabled = false
            private val _batteryInfoMap = MutableLiveData<HashMap<String, Int>>()

            val batteryInfo: LiveData<HashMap<String, Int>>
                get() = _batteryInfoMap

            init {
                _lifecycle.addObserver(this)
            }

            private val broadcastBatteryInfoListener = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

                override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

                    intent?.let {

                        val level = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
                        val temperature = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1)
                        val voltage = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1)
                        val technology = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY, -1)
                        val plugged = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)
                        val health = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, -1)

                        map["level"] = level
                        map["temperature"] = temperature

                        _batteryInfoMap.value = map
                    }
                }
            }


            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
            fun start() {
                if (_enabled) {
                    _context.registerReceiver(
                        broadcastBatteryInfoListener,
                        IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
                    )
                }
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
            fun stop() {
                _context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastBatteryInfoListener)
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
            fun destroy() {
                _lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
            }

            fun enable() {
                _enabled = true

                if (_lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
                    start()
                }
            }
        }
```

**And inside MainActivity onCreate()**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val into = BatteryInfo(this, lifecycle)
        into.enable()

        into.batteryInfo.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d("TAG", "${it.values}")

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple listener would work :

```
data class Stats(val level : Int,
                 val temp : Int,
                 val voltage : Int,
                 val technology : Int,
                 val plugged : Int,
                 val health : Int)


class BatteryInfo(
    private val _context: Context,
    private val _lifecycle: Lifecycle
): LifecycleObserver {

    private var _enabled = false
    private var listener: ((Stats) -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        _lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    private val broadcastBatteryInfoListener = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

            intent?.let {

                val level = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
                val temperature = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1)
                val voltage = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1)
                val technology = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY, -1)
                val plugged = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)
                val health = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, -1)

                listener?.invoke(Stats(level, temperature, voltage, technology, plugged, health))
                //  Log.d("TAG", String.format("%.1f", voltage / 1000f) + " V")
            }
        }
    }

    fun setListener(listener: ((Stats) -> Unit)?) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun start() {
        //  if (_enabled) {
        _context.registerReceiver(broadcastBatteryInfoListener,
            IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
        )
        // }
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun stop() {
        _context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastBatteryInfoListener)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun destroy() {
        _lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
        listener = null
    }


    // connect if not connected
    fun enable() {
        _enabled = true

        if (_lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)) {
            start()
        }
    }
}

class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        BatteryInfo(this, lifecycle)
            .apply { setListener { stats: Stats -> Log.d(TAG, stats.toString()) } }

    }
}
```

Comment: Will this create multiple objects of Stats class??

Comment: Yes, because battery stats are a transient state - they will change, hence the point of the broadcast receiver in the first place.

Comment: Hmm I think lately you can use `DefaultLifecycleObserver` instead of `@OnLifecycleEvent`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it was a minimal change to OP's code - I wouldn't write it this way from scratch. However not sure what OP's requirements are based on their comment, and not really worth pursuing, even though their answer uses a listener like mine ...

Comment: @Mark Keen --> Is this not a bad idea to create multiple objects of Stats class for this little work. So I planned to work with LiveData. But if you think there is another best solution or your existing solution is best please tell me because I want only the best. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I know its not you answer but its a different approach of getting things done. It also removes all of your boilerplate code.

You can use an object to extract all your data from intent and return an instance of your data class. 
Read more about object in kotlin here - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html

```
object BatteryInfoUtils {

      fun getBatteryInfoFromIntent(intent: Intent): Stats { intent?.let {

                    val level = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
                    val temperature = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1)
                    val voltage = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1)
                    val technology = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY, -1)
                    val plugged = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1)
                    val health = it.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, -1)



                  return Stats(level, temperature, voltage, technology, plugged, health)
                }
}
```

And inside MainActivity onCreate()

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     val stats = getBatteryInfo()

 }

fun getBatteryInfo(): Stats? {
 var stats: Stats? = null
 val intent: Intent? = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED).let { ifilter ->
                registerReceiver(null, ifilter)
            }
 intent?.let { batteryIntent ->
                stats = BatteryInfoUtils.getBatteryInfoFromIntent(batteryIntent)
  }
 return stats
}
```